# NextJS localStorage.getItem() method not working on components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

In my `nextjs`-app I want to use `localstorage`, to store some values across my application.

so inside the `pages`-folder I have a `[slug].tsx`-file where I do this:

```
export default function Page({ data}) {

   useEffect(() => {
     const page = {
       title: data.page.title,
       subtitle: data.page.subtitle,
       slug: data.page.slug,
     }

     localStorage.setItem("page", JSON.stringify(page))
  })

  return ( ... some html....)
}
```

this basically stores the title, subtitle and slug for the current route.

Now, inside my `components`-folder I have a `Nav.tsx`-file, where I do this:

```
const Nav= () => {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
     const current = JSON.parse(localStoraget.getItem('page'))
     if(current){
        setPageData(current)
     }
  },[])

  return(...some html)

 }
```

So far, the `setItem` works and in the `application`-tab of the google inspector I can see, that the key-values changes, each time a new route/page gets rendered BUT the `getItem`- always returns the same e.g. the key values do not change at all. What am I doing wrong? Is it maybe because the `Nav` component only gets rendered once?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Yes, the Nav component renders once and that's when the useEffect is called. useEffect needs a value inside the [] and it will be called everytime this value is changed.

Answer (score 1):

you have a spelling error from:

```
localStoraget.getItem('page')
```

to:

```
localStorage.getItem('page')
```

believe your issue also falls under `localstorage` should be used with async/await so maybe try something like:

```
const Nav= () => {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    async function settingData() {
      const current = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('page'))
      if(current)setPageData(current)
    }
    settingData()
  },[])

  return(...some html)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: You should avoid using `localStorage` to share the state over your App. React provides a good way of doing it with ContextAPI or you could use another lib such as Redux/MobX/Recoil.**

At the time when the `<Nav>` component is rendered (and the `useEffect` runs) the `localStorage` probably still doesn't have the key-value set.

If you really want to use `localStorage` (but I suggest not using it), you can create a timeout to execute after some time and will try to get again the value. Something like this could work:

```js
let localStorageTimer = null;

const Nav = () => {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const getLocalStorageItems = () => {
      const current = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('page'))
      if (!current) {
        localStorageTimer = setTimeout(() => getLocalStorageItems, 1000);
      } else {
        clearTimeout(localStorageTimer)
        setPageData(current)
      }
    }

    localStorageTimer = setTimeout(() => getLocalStorageItems, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(localStorageTimer)
  }, []);

  return (.. your JSX code)
}
```